# CSS3 Box-Shadow Showing Behind Sibling Div Element

Tags: css

I'm using:

```
box-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #333333;
```

on my footer but it's hiding behind or disappearing where the `div` before it is... hard to explain but here's what it looks like: http://cl.ly/7HLy

Is there a way do have the box-shadow be on top of the other div before the footer? I've tried adding a z-index but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you adding position:relative with the z-index?

Comment: You should share a live link or a [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/), or it's guesswork.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I'll repeat my comment here since it solved the problem.

When using `z-index` you should use `position: relative;`